# Calculate mean, median and mode for each column in table and transpose so there is one row per column and the aggregates are columns (not using union)

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table with numerical columns x,y & z. For data quality purposes I want to calculate the mean, median and mode for each column and present as rows, like so:

https://ibb.co/HFz1qTw

The end goal is to create an up-to-date table like the one in sys.all_columns (I'm not admin)

Is there an elegant way to do this (preferably dynamically so I don't have to enter every column name, while not using UNION) ?

Answer (score 0):

Feasible but complex.

Here are the steps :

- 1 : Generates dynamically the SQL to compute mean, median... for the columns you want
- 2 : Run the query as dynamic cursor.

If you need it to like really easy to use at the end, you can use a pipelined function :

- 3 : So basically create a function that takes as an argument the table name and will be used like :

  select * from table(MyPipelinedFunction(MyTableName));
- 4 : And you will easily get the result

Here are some tips on each step :

## Step 1 : generate SQL dynamically

```
SQL := 'Select average(#FIELD1#), mean or median(#FIELD2#)... from #TABLE#';
SQL := replace(SQL,'#FIELD1#','Whatever');
SQL := replace(SQL,'#TABLE#','Whatever');
```

## Step 2 : Run the query as dynamic cursor.

```
    Declare
        RefCursor      SYS_REFCURSOR;
        Mean           number;
        Median         nuber;               
        ...
    BEGIN
        OPEN RefCursor FOR SQL;             
        FETCH RefCursor INTO Mean, Median...;               
        CLOSE RefCursor;
```

## Step 3 : pipelined function

```
    TYPE Statistics IS RECORD(Mean NUMBER, MEdian Number, ...);   
    TYPE StatisticsTable IS TABLE OF Statistics;       
    
    FUNCTION ComputeStatistics(TableName in varchar2) RETURN Statistics PIPELINED IS    
        S Statistics;
    BEGIN
    
        -- Get the table field names in case they are different using a static cursor
        SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS where table_name = upper(TableName);
        
        -- Use the results to build the SQL query and run the dynamic cursor as in Step 1 & 2
        -- After this step, results are stored in the variables Mean, Median...
        
        -- Output result
        S := Statistics(Mean, Median, ...);
        
        PIPE ROW (S);
        RETURN;
    END ComputeStatistics;
```

## Step 4 : Get the result

```
    select * from table(ComputeStatistics('WhateverTable');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just unpivot and aggregate:

```
select c.col,
       min(c.val), max(c.val), avg(c.val), median(c.val), stats_mode(c.val)
from t cross join lateral
     (select 'x' as col, x as val from dual union all
      select 'y', y from dual union all
      select 'z', z from dual 
     ) c
group by c.col;
```

You can turn this into dynamic SQL using PL/SQL.  In practice, though, I would just query for the column names and generate the SQL directly:

```
select replace('
    select [col] as col,
           min(t.[col]), max(t.[col]), avg(t.[col]), median(t.[col]), stats_mode(t.[col])
    from t t union all
', '[col]', column_name)
from sys.all_tab_columns c join
     sys.all_tables t
     on c.owner = t.owner and
        c.table_name = t.table_name;
```

You can then just remove the last `union all` and run the code.

Note:  This doesn't use `listagg()` because of limits on string length.  But you can combine this logic into a single string if you don't have too many columns.

Comment: Hi, I get "quoted string not properly terminated" when trying that. Care to double-check?